# How to reliably determine jpeg image resolution with Pillow

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, jpeg

If the Pillow Info DPI field has no value, how can an image's resolution be determined? Note that this is for jpeg files for which other image processing programs are able to correctly identify the resolution. Following is the code I am using to read the jpeg dpi value.

```
from PIL import Image
jpgfile='someimage.jpg'
im = Image.open(jpgfile)
dpi = im.info.get('dpi')
print("\n dpi: ", type(dpi), "  ", dpi)
```

The expected output is:

```
dpi:  <kbd> class 'tuple' (999, 999)
```

where '999' is the x and y resolution.

However, many images result in the following output

```
dpi class 'NoneType' None
```

In these instances (which are all too common), how can I get the image's resolution?

Answer (score 0):

The data that can be returned by the .info.get method is stored in a dictionary that is not universally used by the various devices and programs that write exif data to image files. If it's returning "None," it's because nothing had been put there in the first place, or since there's no standard for how data is stored in it, in a key-value pair you're not expecting.

The larger issue here is that DPI is not a fixed property of an image--it's a term that's relative to the expected size of the image as printed on paper or screen. If, for instance, you display a jpg produced by a digital camera or cell-phone directly on a monitor screen, it will typically be displayed at 72dpi and you'll be able to see only a small portion of the image. At that resolution, the full-sized image would be huge--more than a meter wide and proportionally height. But if printed at, say, 300dpi, the whole image might fit nicely on an 8.5x11/A4 sheet of paper.

Since the camera or program doesn't necessary know how the image will be displayed or printed, it doesn't necessarily include resolution information in the EXIF data. More accessible is the data on the absolute size of the image in pixels: x wide and y high. Given those dimensions, the "dpi" of the image entirely depends on the physical size (in imperial inches: dots-per-inch) of the image output to paper or screen.